# Bitset as the return value of a function

Tags: c++, bitset, boost-dynamic-bitset, std-bitset

I'd like to have an interface whose function returns a bitset:

```
class IMyInterface
{
public:
    virtual std::bitset<100> GetBits() = 0;
};
```

The problem is that I don't want to force the size of the `bitset`. So I think I have to use `boost::dynamic_bitset` instead:

```
class IMyInterface
{
public:
    virtual boost::dynamic_bitset<> GetBits() = 0;
};
```

I have heard that `boost::dynamic_bitset` is slower than `std::bitset` though. Is there any other way to avoid using `dynamic_bitset` and have an interface that returns a `std::bitset` whose size is determined by the implementors?

Comment: You can make the interface a template itself.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, due to its static-ness, `std::bitset` [is not considered to be a good solution](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/). Apart from `boost::` stuff, you may use things like...

```
template<size_t N>
class IMyInterface {
    public:
        virtual std::bitset<N> GetBits() = 0;
};
```

But that would still be too static, no? Well, [the standards specify that there's an specialization of `std::vector<bool>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector-bool/), that is usually implemented as a dynamic, memory-efficient `std::bitset`! So...

```
#include <vector>

class IMyInterface {
    public:
        virtual std::vector<bool>& GetBits() = 0;
};
```

**Edit**: Made `IMyInterface::GetBits()` return a reference for efficiency purposes.

Comment: A reference wouldn't make a difference for the return value, since we have RVO already.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That's not *necessary* nor *mandated by the standards*. And, after all, whatever that return value optimization does, passing a reference/pointer around will always be the cheapest.

Comment: On the other hand specifying a reference return value in an interface forces an implementations inner details.

Comment: Doing bitwise operations on `std::vector<bool>` would not be easy.

Comment: @Meysam Yes, that's another fair point, the interfaces are very different.